# How to update useReducer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am using NextJS and Material-UI.
I want to create a slider, where I can choose name or name2. I created a sendbox for better unterstanding: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/project-forked-q9kbs?file=/components/RenderDatatype.js). I cant move my slider in the moment. I dont`know, what is actually the problem there.(renderdatatype component )

Also I dont know how do update for the type slider the state.(FormComponent) I am using useReducer for the react hook.

this is my slider:

```
 case "Slider":
            return (
                 <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                    <Slider
                        max={0}
                        max={100}
                        step={50}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom" 
                        />
                    <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                        <Typography>
                        {name}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography >
                        {name2}
                        </Typography>
                    </div>  
                    
                </Grid>
            );
```

```
const handleReducer = (state, action) => {
   
    switch (action.type) {
      case "Checkbox":
        state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value = !state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value;
        return [...state];
      case "Slider":
        state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value = 70;
        return [...state];
      case "TextField":
        // Manipulate text input state 
        return [...state];
      case "Rating":
        // Manipulate rating state
        return [...state];
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

 const Form = ()  => {

    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
    const [jobData, dispatchjobData] = useReducer(handleReducer,jobdata.softwareentwicklerfields);
    const [personaltyData, dispatchPersonaltyData] = useReducer(handleReducer,personalty.personaltyfields);
    const [contactData, dispatchcontactData] = useReducer(handleReducer, contact.contactfields);

    const handleNext = () =>{
      setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1)
    };

    const handleBack = () => {
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
    };

    //Handle fields change for checkboxes
    const handleChange = useCallback(
      (index, innerIndex, type, value) => {
        console.log("handleChange");
        console.log("value", value);
        switch (activeStep) {
          case 0:
            dispatchjobData({index, innerIndex,type, value });
            break;
          case 1:
            dispatchPersonaltyData({index, innerIndex, type, value});
            break;
          case 2:
            dispatchcontactData({ index, innerIndex, type, value  });
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      [activeStep]
    );
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems i see with your code.  1- You assign "max" twice to the slider. Second your components should be separated.... not some switch rendering them based on "type".  Third each component should be responsible for fetching and modifying its own data.  Last your reducer logic seems flawed and it has 70 harcoded as the value for the slider.

Comment: Its hardcoded, because I dont have any idea to do it. how would you do it? And thanks for the other ideas.